# Can you get the object of a method?

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering if I can make some of my helper functions(for stuff like benching, logging and caching) a bit neater. Right now I'm doing this

```
function doSomethingToMethodsObject(object, methodname) {
    //do things to object and object[methodname]
}
```

so I can use it like this

```
var myObject = function() {
    this.myString = "hello";
    this.myMethod = function() { return this.myString; }.bind(this);
    doSomethingToMethodsObject(this, "myMethod");
}
```

but it would be better if I could call it like this

```
doSomethingToMethodsObject(this.myMethod);
```

and then break down the function reference to this and "myMethod" inside doSomethingToMethodsObject.

So is there a way to figure out what objects a function belongs to?

Comment: assign `this` to variable and use it like `var self = this;`
`this.myMethod = function() { return self.myString; }.bind(selft);`

Comment: What exactly are those "things" you do to `object`?

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way to figure out what objects a function belongs to?

A function does not belong to only a single object.  There can be lots of references to that same function on lots of different objects.  So, no you can't specifically figure out what object a function belongs to by purely looking at the function.

In fact, why you pass `this.myMethod` as an argument, there is no connection whatsoever to the `this` part that is passed.  It just gets a reference to the function and passes that.

You can use `.bind()` to pass a bound reference to the function, but that only lets you call the method in the context of the right object - it doesn't allow you to separate out the object from the method.  If you need both object and method separately in your function, then you will need to find some way to make them both separately accessible inside the function - the most obvious way to do that is just pass them both as arguments.

Depending upon the specific context (which you don't really share very much of), sometimes you can use parent scoped variables like `var self = this;` to maintain a reference to `this` that can be accessed by child functions, but I'm not sure that applies to what you're doing.

Here are some options:

```
doSomethingToMethodsObject(this, this.myMethod);

doSomethingToMethodsObject({obj: this, method: this.myMethod});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `this.myMethod`, JS creates a reference whose base is `this` and whose referenced name is `"myMethod"`.

However, when you use it as an argument, JS resolves the reference into the property value. Therefore, in `doSomethingToMethodsObject`, it's too late to get the base.

The only way to obtain the base of `this.myMethod` is when `myMethod` is an accessor property with a getter which redirects to the underlying object value. Then you can use `this` inside the getter, and store it in a property of the underlying value.

For example:

```
var obj = {
  _myMethod: function(arg) { /* Underlying function */
    return {thisArg: this, arg: arg};
  },
  get myMethod() { /* Stores reference parts and redirects */
    return Object.assign(this._myMethod, {
      refBase: this,
      refName: "_myMethod"
    });
  }
};
function doSomethingToMethodsObject(value) {
  return value.call(
    value.refBase,
    value === value.refBase[value.refName]
  );
}
obj.myMethod(123); // {thisArg: obj, arg: 123}
doSomethingToMethodsObject(obj.myMethod); // {thisArg: obj, arg: true}
```

Comment: Of course, this approach destroys normal `this.myMethod()` calls

Comment: @Bergi Good point. I guess the getter could return a function which redirects calls to `_myMethod` (or `_myMethod` itself), and store `this` as a property of that function.